# User management + grant

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with multiple tables, functions, sequences, and types inside.

I want to create multiple "administrator"-like users:

- they all might have all privileges to manage everything (existing and newly created items) in this database;
- they all have the same privileges;
- they might cross-manage entities (table created by administrator `a` should be available for a removal for administrator `b`)

I tried to create something like this, but failed on types:

```
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE {dbname} TO {rw_user};"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO {rw_user};"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO {rw_user};"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO {rw_user};"
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TYPES IN SCHEMA public TO {rw_user};" --not exists
"ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO {rw_user};"
"ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO {rw_user};"
"ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO {rw_user};"
"ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TYPES TO {rw_user};"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do that (if you don't want a shared database user) is the following:

```
CREATE ROLE admins;
CREATE ROLE a LOGIN NOINHERIT IN ROLE admins;
CREATE ROLE b LOGIN NOINHERIT IN ROLE admins;
CREATE SCHEMA shared;
GRANT CREATE; USAGE ON SCHEMA shared TO admins;
```

Then neither `a` nor `b` can create objects in `shared` unless they do the following:

```
SET ROLE admins;
CREATE TABLE shared.newtab (...);
RESET ROLE;
```

Such a table is then owned by `admins`, and both `a` and `b` can `ALTER` or `DROP` it.

Note that `ALTER` and `DROP` are restricted to the owner of the object, and you cannot `GRANT` these rights.